# Http redirect form OAuth2-Server: how are values added as url hash?

Tags: oauth-2.0, implicit-flow

Let's say, in Oauth implicit flow,  the `redirect uri` I provided is `http://www.abc.de/de`

Then the oauth2-server will responde with a `302` and the `location` will say something like:

```
http://www.abc.de/de#access_token=blabla&token_type=bearer
```

Then my browser redirects me to `http://www.abc.de/de` without the url hash part, right?

How is the url hash added to my redirect uri? Does the Outh2-server simply add it and then set the `location` to that value?

And how do I know that the value given in the `access_token` is trustworthy? The `location` is part of the http request right? So while url hashes are not sent to the server, the `location` value could be intercepted and meddled with by a MITM attack.

Or am I mixing things up here?

Answer (score 0):

i think the identity server will never send those token back unless the url is added to trusted urls on the server.
so if someone create a page in the middle and make people authenticate on it, will never get the token back because the client url is not trusted